# How to pick a row from a table then add it to another table

Tags: matlab

guys, I have two matrices like below. I want to compare the second column of the first matrix with the first column of the second matrix. If they are the same I want to copy that row to another matrix. I gave an example below. Thank you so much.

```
  Matrix 1                               Matrix 2 
3323    918                     918 2   12  13
2522    842                     918 2   9   13
3049    918                     918 2   6   13
1143    40                      918 2   3   1
204     1                       842 2   3   8
1663    362                     842 3   12  9
2079    362                     842 3   9   3
770     1                       40  3   9   6
2189    842                     40  3   6   9
                                40  3   3   5

Expected Result
918 2   12  13
918 2   9   13
918 2   6   13
918 2   3   1
842 2   3   8
842 3   12  9
842 3   9   3
918 2   12  13
918 2   9   13
918 2   6   13
918 2   3   1
40  3   9   6
40  3   6   9
40  3   3   5
842 2   3   8
842 3   12  9
842 3   9   3
```

Comment: Explain once again what logic rule will create Matrix 3. Why it is longer than 1 and 2, and has some rows repeated?

Comment: @Karls As per my understanding: `Matrix1(1,2)` is `918`. The OP selects all the rows whose first element is `918` and so on for other elements of `Matrix1`. `Matrix1(3,2)` is again `918` and hence again all those rows are selected.

Answer (score 0):

As your metod to generate result_Matrix (call it `RM`) is a bit descriptive, the method will also be a bit complicated. First you have to analyse Marix 2 (I will call it `M2`). You can use simple loop:

```
i=1;
M2_indexes=[1];
for idx=1:size(M2)
    if M2(idx)~=M2(M2_indexes(i))
        M2_indexes=[M2_indexes, idx];
        i=i+1;
    end
end
M2_indexes=[M2_indexes,(size(M2,1)+1)];
```

Now your program knows that the value changes at `[1 5 8]` and the last index in the range of matrix is `[11]`. It's a time to iteratively loop through `M1`. It's very similar to previous step:
MR=[];

```
for idx=1:size(M1)
    for idy=1:size(M2_indexes,2)
        if M2(M2_indexes(idy))==M1(idx,2)
            MR=[MR; M2(M2_indexes(idy):(M2_indexes(idy+1)-1),1:4)];
        end
    end
end
```

And the result is as you described:

```
MR =

   918     2    12    13
   918     2     9    13
   918     2     6    13
   918     2     3     1
   842     2     3     8
   842     3    12     9
   842     3     9     3
   918     2    12    13
   918     2     9    13
   918     2     6    13
   918     2     3     1
    40     3     9     6
    40     3     6     9
    40     3     3     5
   842     2     3     8
   842     3    12     9
   842     3     9     3
```